# Trigger only when updated column has a different value

Tags: sql, derby

I have a table, PERSON, that has a column LAST_VISIT (among others). I'm trying to create a trigger so that when PERSON is updated and **only if LAST_VISIT is changed** from the previous value, I insert a row into a different table. Is this possible? What I've tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_last_visit_changed
    AFTER UPDATE ON PERSON
    REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
    INSERT INTO
        ALERT (
            TYPE,
            ENTITY_ID
        )
        VALUES
        (
            'LAST_VISIT_ALERT',
            OLD.ID,
        )
    WHERE OLD.LAST_VISIT !=  NEW.LAST_VISIT;
```

But I get a syntax error:

```
Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE"
```

Which makes sense I guess because the [trigger syntax](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj43125.html#rrefsqlj43125__i1149821) doesn't seem to allow this. Is there a different way to do this? I was considering using exceptions to stop the trigger when the condition `OLD.LAST_VISIT !=  NEW.LAST_VISIT` isn't met, but I wasn't sure how to do this or if that was considered bad practice.

Comment: A Derby trigger can invoke a function or procedure written in Java. For an example, see: https://deepakjha.wordpress.com/2007/09/17/utilizing-javas-power-in-derby-database-triggers/

Answer (score 0):

Insert from a select:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_last_visit_changed
AFTER UPDATE ON PERSON
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
INSERT INTO ALERT (
    TYPE,
    ENTITY_ID
)
SELECT
    'LAST_VISIT_ALERT',
    OLD.ID
FROM DUAL
WHERE OLD.LAST_VISIT !=  NEW.LAST_VISIT;
```

Comment: I get `Syntax error: Encountered "IF"`. Please note I'm using derby DB (as tagged).